Function field of abelian varieties
Notation I consider smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. $A$ is an abelian variety and $\hat{A}$ is its dual. $k(X)$ is the field of functions of a variety $X$.
Context I try to understand the relation between $D$-equivalence in derived geometry and $K$-equivalence in birational geometry. It is well known that $D \implies K$ on a general type variety, but it seems false for a general variety. So I try to understand the toy example of abelian varieties. We know that $A$ and $\hat{A}$ are derived equivalents, and their canonical bundle is trivial, so we just have to find if they are birationals : $ k(A) \simeq k(\hat{A})$ ?
This assertion is stated to be false in the literature : there are abelian varieties non birationals to their duals ; however I don't find any reference so I try to construct an example by myself.
I know how to produce an $A$ such that $A \not\simeq \hat{A}$, but I don't think it is enough to conclude. $A$ and $\hat{A}$ are at least isogenous, and the previous construction only ensures that any isogeny is of degree $>1$. However we may have
$$ k(A) \hookrightarrow k(\hat{A}) \hookrightarrow k(A)$$
with both morphisms of degree $>1$, and still $k(A) \simeq k(\hat{A})$.  By Luröth theorem this is the case for the function field of $\mathbb{P}^1$, but I don't know if this situation can happen for abelian varieties.
So do you know anything about $k(A)$ and $k(\hat{A})$ to help me in my problem ?
Remark I think $k(A)$ have a coalgebra structure due to the functoriality of the multiplication map, but I don't know if this fact is useful.

A birational map between abelian varieties is an isomorphism.
